# How to reduce Ignite heap size

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ignite

I'm running Ignite inside Spring Boot application. It is showing heap size of 1.7 GB. Following is the screenshot when it boots up:

[image]

I tried reducing it by setting following maven options but it didn't work:

> -Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+UseG1GC

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to `-Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:+UseG1GC`? Note that 200M is pretty lowball for Apache Ignite. My recommendation is to use half gigabyte heap or more.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following (note that it is Linux):

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+UseG1GC"
mvn spring-boot:run
```

and what I get is:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, offheap=6.3GB, heap=0.2GB]
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200m -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

Comment: I'm running the spring boot using the command `mvn spring-boot:run`. But still I am not getting the result you are getting. Also, I tried what you said in a newly built Spring Boot application with just ignite which does nothing and then I'm getting the same result as yours. But this isn't working for my main application which I want to fix.

Comment: Also I'm unable to run the application with the command you mentioned, it is saying `The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]`. Here's the command which I ran `mvn exec:java -DIGNITE_QUITE=false -Dexec.mainClass=com.****.****.Application`.

Comment: I have switched it to `spring-boot:run` and it is exactly the same. what OS are you using?

Comment: Kali Linux (Debian Derivative)